# Composite and Terms Aggregations on a field with a high cardinality

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, query-optimization, aggregation, cardinality

I am facing a huge performance problem with ES which results in more than 2 min response.

I have an index that has more than 25M files and composes of the next 4 fields (among others):

```
...

       "group_write": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        },
        "user_write": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        },
        "group_read": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        },
        "user_read": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }

...
```

I have something like 100K unique users and groups and each field is a list of users/groups that holds ~100 values. For example:

```
"user_read": ["user_1", "group_1", ...],
"user_write": ["user_1", "group_2", ...]
...
```

I have 2 kinds of aggregation I am using, composite and terms. Composite aggregations for getting only first X results to display and terms aggregation for prefix search.

Composite aggregation:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "Group_Read_Permissions": {
            "composite": {
                "sources": [
                    {
                        "Group Read": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "group_read.raw"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "size": 10
            }
        },
        "Group_Write_Permissions": {
            "composite": {
                "sources": [
                    {
                        "Group Write": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "group_write.raw"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "User_Write_Permissions": {
            "composite": {
                "sources": [
                    {
                        "User Write": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "user_write.raw"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "User_Read_Permissions": {
            "composite": {
                "sources": [
                    {
                        "User Read": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "user_read.raw"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Terms aggregation:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "Group_Read_Permissions": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "group_read.raw",
                "include": ".*[Ss].*"
            }
        },
        "Group Write Permissions": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "group_write.raw",
                "include": ".*[Ss].*"
            }
        },
        "User Read Permissions": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "user_read.raw",
                "include": ".*[Ss].*"
            }
        },
        "User Write Permissions": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "user_write.raw",
                "include": ".*[Ss].*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Composite aggregation returns results within 1 min and the terms aggregation can take up to 5 min.

What I have tried so far:

1. Adding new field `user_group_permissions` and adding to the above 4 fields `"copy_to": "user_group_permissions"`
2. Adding to the above 4 fields and to the field "user_group_permissions" the next property: `"eager_global_ordinals": true`
3. Increased the `refresh_interval` up to 200s

** I reindexed for the first 2 suggestions [took something like 6 hours]

All of the above did help a little with the retrieval time but still: composite aggregation takes up to 20s and terms aggregation takes up to 3 min.
[The best results were on the fields `user_group_permissions` which has been created in the first suggestion, with `eager_global_ordinals` = true and `refresh_interval` = 120s].

Please, if someone has any idea how to improve the retrieval times I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you only need the first 10 results, you don't need to use the `composite` aggregation, which is meant to be used only if you need to paginate over **all** results. Simply use the `terms` aggregation with default size 10, that'll do the job.

Second, what you're doing with the `terms` aggregation is not a prefix filtering, but **infix filtering**, which is completely different in terms of performance. While it's easy to search for prefixes, searching for infixes requires the equivalent of a "full table scan" because each and every term must be visited.

A first optimization I would suggest is that in your second query you should do your regex in the query part (`bool/should` with one `regex` query per field), so as to reduce the document set on which the terms aggregations need to run. That might help a bit.

A second optimization is to leverage the [`wildcard` field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type) which is a specialized field type made specially for grep-like `wildcard` and `regexp` queries.

Another possible optimization is to lowercase all your permissions, so that you only need to search for `.*s.*` instead of the uppercase variant.

Depending on your comments, I'll add more optimizations as the discussion goes on.

Comment: First, thanks for the reply!
The composite aggregation was used since it is not sorting the results as opposed to the terms aggregation, therefore making it a faster one.

Regarding the prefix filtering you are absolutely right, the intention was prefix and not infix. I did fix the query but still faced a long retrieving time(220s).

Some conclusions about the suggestions:
1. A query of regex for each field indeed helped a little but not significantly.
2. wildcard and lowercase have not optimized the aggregation, wildcard even made it slower a little. 

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Ok, you can still use the `terms` aggregation and sort by key instead of sorting by count. Thanks for testing the suggestions. Concerning 1, yes that was expected as `regexp` queries are resource hogs. I'm surprised the wildcard field type doesn't help, though. Note that I'm not talking about the `wildcard` query, which is something different.

Comment: Yes, I have reindexed after changing the field type to wildcard and it was slower. Do you think that maintaining a list of values inside those fields is the right call? I think that nested might be slower but not for sure, what do you think?

Comment: What kills your performance is the fact that you're searching within the string (i.e. infix). Another optimization that could help here (if used properly) is to use an [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) (+ lowercase), it will make your index a tad bigger, but it could solve the infix search problem and might even get rid of the need for regexp.